# Battery draining much faster

Tags: huawei

I have rooted by Huawei Honor 3X using this procedure http://playfuldroid.com/how-to-root-huawei-honor-3x-tutorial/ , but it seems like my battery are draining slightly faster. Should I unroot my device, or could it be because of the live wall paper?

Answer (score 1):

Rooting should not affect battery life, unless you have unlocked bootloader too and installed some mods/tweaks or whole custom ROM. You can check the apps with root access, if they're not causing the problem.